# Globally accessible sass variables in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

My goal is to get the following code working in `.vue` files in Laravel project:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
    @import 'variables'; // <-- file not found

    // ...
</style>
```

Currently, whenever I try to run the above code, the "file not found" error is thrown by the sass compiler.

My current `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
       resolve: {
           alias: {
               tools: 'resources/assets/sass/tools' // <-- does not work
           }
       }
   });
```

So the question is, how do I configure laravel-mix, so that I am able to include global sass files **without having to use relative paths**?

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me :

```
const path = require('path')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

resolve: {
    alias: { 
        'blah': resolve('resources/assets/sass/blah')
    }
}

@import '~blah/blah'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global variable, do not use  `scoped` in the `<style>` tag